# After the latest update two errors appeared with (checkDebugDuplicateClasses and mergeDebugJavaResource)

Tags: java, android, kotlin

The application was working fine, but after the latest update, the two errors below appeared.
I can't find the solution to this one. If anyone can help,
Thank you...

> Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialogDefaults found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialogKt found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialogKt$AlertDialogContent$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialogKt$AlertDialogContent$1$1$1$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialogKt$AlertDialogContent$1$1$2$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialogKt$AlertDialogContent$1$1$2$1$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialogKt$AlertDialogContent$1$1$3$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialogKt$AlertDialogContent$1$1$3$1$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialogKt$AlertDialogContent$1$1$4$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialogKt$AlertDialogContent$2 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialogKt$AlertDialogFlowRow$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialogKt$AlertDialogFlowRow$1$measure$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AlertDialogKt$AlertDialogFlowRow$2 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AndroidAlertDialog_androidKt found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AndroidAlertDialog_androidKt$AlertDialog$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AndroidAlertDialog_androidKt$AlertDialog$1$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AndroidAlertDialog_androidKt$AlertDialog$1$1$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AndroidAlertDialog_androidKt$AlertDialog$2 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AndroidMenu_androidKt found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AndroidMenu_androidKt$DropdownMenu$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AndroidMenu_androidKt$DropdownMenu$2 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AndroidMenu_androidKt$DropdownMenu$popupPositionProvider$1$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AndroidMenu_androidKt$DropdownMenuItem$2 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AppBarKt found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AppBarKt$BottomAppBar$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AppBarKt$BottomAppBar$2 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AppBarKt$BottomAppBar$3 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AppBarKt$BottomAppBar$4 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AppBarKt$CenterAlignedTopAppBar$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AppBarKt$LargeTopAppBar$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AppBarKt$MediumTopAppBar$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AppBarKt$SingleRowTopAppBar$1$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AppBarKt$SingleRowTopAppBar$2 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AppBarKt$SingleRowTopAppBar$3 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AppBarKt$SingleRowTopAppBar$actionsRow$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)
> Duplicate class androidx.compose.material3.AppBarKt$SingleRowTopAppBar$appBarDragModifier$1$1 found in modules jetified-material3-1.1.0-alpha02-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3:1.1.0-alpha02) and jetified-material3-release-runtime (androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02)

The second error 'app:mergeDebugJavaResource'

> What went wrong:
> Execution failed for task ':app:mergeDebugJavaResource'.
> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.MergeJavaResWorkAction
> 2 files found with path 'META-INF/androidx.compose.material3_material3.version' from inputs

build.gradle

```
plugins {
    id 'com.android.application'
    id 'org.jetbrains.kotlin.android'
    id 'kotlin-android-extensions'
    id 'kotlin-kapt'
    id 'dagger.hilt.android.plugin'
    id 'com.google.firebase.crashlytics'
    id 'kotlin-android'
    id "androidx.navigation.safeargs.kotlin"
    id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
    id 'com.google.firebase.firebase-perf'
}

android {
    namespace 'com.elto.dateT'
    compileSdk 33

    buildFeatures {
        compose true
        dataBinding true
        viewBinding true
    }

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.elto.dateT"
        minSdk 30
        targetSdk 33
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        renderscriptSupportModeEnabled true
        manifestPlaceholders = [file_provider: "dev.demoserver.com"]

        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"

        javaCompileOptions {
            annotationProcessorOptions {
                arguments += ["room.schemaLocation":
                                     "$projectDir/schemas".toString()]
            }
        }
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
        benchmark {
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
            matchingFallbacks = ['release']
            debuggable false
        }
    }
    viewBinding {
        enabled = true
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_11
    }
    composeOptions {
        kotlinCompilerVersion "1.5.10"
        kotlinCompilerExtensionVersion = "1.4.0-alpha02"
    }
    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation(platform("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-bom:1.8.0"))
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.6.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.8.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:2.1.4'

    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-fragment-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation 'androidx.navigation:navigation-ui-ktx:2.5.3'
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3"
    implementation 'androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.0.0'
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.startup:startup-runtime:1.1.1"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-alpha07"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.4.2"
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview-selection:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'
    //
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.3.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.9.1'
    implementation 'androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1'
    implementation 'androidx.core:core-ktx:1.10.0'
    implementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit-ktx:1.1.5'
    implementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1'
    implementation project(path: ':mediafacer')
    // Client + offline + UI components
    implementation "io.getstream:stream-chat-android-ui-components:5.17.0"
    // Client + offline
    implementation "io.getstream:stream-chat-android-offline:5.17.0"
    // Client only
    implementation "io.getstream:stream-chat-android-client:5.17.0"
    implementation("io.getstream:stream-log:1.1.4")
    implementation "io.getstream:stream-chat-android-compose:5.17.0"
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui-tooling-preview:1.5.0-alpha03"
    implementation "com.github.skydoves:landscapist-animation:2.1.11"
    implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji-bundled:1.1.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.13.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.5'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:core:1.5.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:runner:1.5.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test:rules:1.5.0'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.5.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-intents:3.5.1'

    //Addition
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:color:3.1.0'
    implementation 'de.hdodenhof:circleimageview:3.1.0'
    implementation 'com.github.adwardstark:materialtextdrawable-for-android:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.jahirfiquitiva:TextDrawable:1.0.3'
    implementation "io.github.l4digital:fastscroll:2.1.0"
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxandroid:2.1.1'
    implementation 'io.reactivex.rxjava2:rxjava:2.2.21'
    implementation 'io.michaelrocks:libphonenumber-android:8.13.7'
    //implementation 'com.1gravity:android-contactpicker:1.4.0'

    implementation 'xyz.danoz:recyclerviewfastscroller:0.1.3'
    implementation("org.greenrobot:eventbus:3.3.1")
    implementation 'com.devbrackets.android:exomedia:5.0.0-beta01'

    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-navigation-compose:1.1.0-alpha01"
    implementation "com.google.dagger:hilt-android:2.45"
    kapt "com.google.dagger:hilt-compiler:2.42"
    testImplementation("com.google.dagger:hilt-android-testing:2.33-beta")
    implementation "androidx.hilt:hilt-compiler:1.0.0"
    implementation "com.google.mlkit:image-labeling:17.0.7"
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore:1.0.0"
    implementation "androidx.datastore:datastore-preferences-core:1.0.0"
    implementation "io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.3.0"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-coil:0.15.0"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager:0.30.1"
    implementation "com.google.accompanist:accompanist-pager-indicators:0.30.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:2.6.1"
    implementation("com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.5.0")
    implementation "androidx.compose.ui:ui:1.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout-compose:1.0.1"
    implementation "androidx.navigation:navigation-compose:2.5.3"
    implementation "com.github.skydoves:landscapist-glide:2.1.11"
    implementation "com.github.skydoves:landscapist-placeholder:2.1.11"
    implementation "com.github.skydoves:retrofit-adapters-result:1.0.6"
    implementation("com.jakewharton.retrofit:retrofit2-kotlinx-serialization-converter:1.0.0")
    implementation("com.github.skydoves:sealedx-core:1.0.1")
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02"
    implementation "androidx.ui:ui-tooling:1.0.0-alpha07"
    implementation "androidx.compose.runtime:runtime-livedata:1.4.2"
    implementation "androidx.compose.material:material-icons-extended:1.5.0-alpha03"
    implementation "androidx.compose.foundation:foundation:1.5.0-alpha03"
    implementation 'androidx.swiperefreshlayout:swiperefreshlayout:1.1.0'
    implementation 'com.facebook.shimmer:shimmer:0.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji:1.2.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji-bundled:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.emoji:emoji-appcompat:1.1.0'

    implementation 'androidx.emoji2:emoji2:1.3.0'
    implementation 'androidx.exifinterface:exifinterface:1.3.6'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v13:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.preference:preference-ktx:1.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.vectordrawable:vectordrawable:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime:2.8.1'
    implementation 'com.google.mlkit:barcode-scanning:17.1.0'

    implementation 'com.googlecode.libphonenumber:libphonenumber:8.13.8'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.71828'

    implementation 'com.dafruits:webrtc:109.0.0'
    implementation 'io.nayuki:qrcodegen:1.8.0'
    coreLibraryDesugaring 'com.android.tools:desugar_jdk_libs:1.2.2'

    implementation 'com.android.installreferrer:installreferrer:2.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.flexbox:flexbox:3.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-oss-licenses:17.0.1'

    api 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.13.5'
    api 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-core:2.13.5'
    api 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-annotations:2.13.5'
    api 'org.java-websocket:Java-WebSocket:1.5.3'
    //noinspection GradleCompatible
    implementation "com.android.support:support-emoji-bundled:26.1.0"
    implementation "com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:21.0.1"
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:18.1.0'
    api 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4'
    def lifecycle_version = "2.6.1"
    def arch_version = "2.2.0"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-compose:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-ktx:$lifecycle_version"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-compose:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-savedstate:$lifecycle_version"

    kapt "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-compiler:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-service:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-process:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-reactivestreams-ktx:$lifecycle_version"

    testImplementation "androidx.arch.core:core-testing:$arch_version"

    testImplementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-runtime-testing:$lifecycle_version"

    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-livedata-ktx:2.6.1"
    
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:2.3.0")
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.3.0")
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-gif:2.2.1")
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-svg:2.1.0")
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-base:2.3.0")
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose-base:2.3.0")
    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil-compose:2.3.0")

    // Coroutine
    implementation 'io.github.ParkSangGwon:tedpermission-coroutine:3.3.0'
    implementation 'com.github.vestrel00:contacts-android:0.2.4'
    configurations.implementation {
        exclude group: 'org.jetbrains.kotlin', module: 'kotlin-stdlib-jdk8'
    }
    implementation("com.himanshoe:pluck:1.0.0-RC2")
    implementation 'com.github.jaiselrahman:FilePicker:1.3.2'
    implementation "com.github.skydoves:landscapist-glide:2.1.11"

    implementation 'com.github.alxrm:audiowave-progressbar:0.9.2'
    implementation 'com.github.Armen101:AudioRecordView:1.0.5'
    implementation 'com.github.GitHubZJY:AudioVisualizeView:v1.0.0'
    implementation  'com.github.massoudss:waveformSeekBar:5.0.2'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.github.squti:Android-Wave-Recorder:1.7.0'
    //for AndroidX use:
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation("io.coil-kt:coil:2.3.0")

    kapt "com.android.databinding:compiler:3.1.4"

    constraints {
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk7 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
        implementation("org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.8.0") {
            because("kotlin-stdlib-jdk8 is now a part of kotlin-stdlib")
        }
    }
    kapt "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.20"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-core:1.6.4"
    api "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-android:1.6.4"

    //glide
    def glide_version = "4.14.2"
    implementation "com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:$glide_version"
    kapt "com.github.bumptech.glide:compiler:$glide_version"

    implementation 'com.karumi:dexter:6.2.3'

    implementation("androidx.room:room-runtime:2.5.1")
    implementation("androidx.room:room-ktx:2.5.1")
    androidTestImplementation("androidx.room:room-testing:2.5.1")
    kapt "androidx.room:room-compiler:2.5.1"

    // Extensions = ViewModel + LiveData
    /*implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.2.0"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-common-java8:2.6.1"
    implementation "androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-viewmodel-ktx:2.6.1"*/

    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.9.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.6.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:4.10.0'
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:logging-interceptor:4.10.0'
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.2.2"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.2.2"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.2.2"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-video:1.2.2"
    implementation 'com.jakewharton.timber:timber:5.0.1'
    implementation 'pub.devrel:easypermissions:3.0.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    implementation "android.arch.lifecycle:extensions:1.1.1"
    implementation 'com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer:2.18.6'
    implementation 'com.github.JarvanMo:ExoVideoView:2.1.6'
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-core:2.18.6"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-dash:2.18.6"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-hls:2.18.6"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-smoothstreaming:2.18.6"
    implementation "com.google.android.exoplayer:exoplayer-ui:2.18.6"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-core:1.2.2"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-camera2:1.2.2"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-lifecycle:1.2.2"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-video:1.2.2"
    implementation "androidx.camera:camera-view:1.2.2"
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-guava:1.6.4"
    implementation 'org.jetbrains.kotlinx:kotlinx-coroutines-play-services:1.6.4'

    implementation "androidx.profileinstaller:profileinstaller:1.3.0"
    implementation 'androidx.annotation:annotation:1.6.0'

    implementation "dev.priyankvasa.android:cameraview-ex:3.5.5-alpha"
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ml-vision:24.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-vision:20.1.3'

    implementation platform('com.google.firebase:firebase-bom:31.2.3')
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-firestore-ktx:24.5.0'
    implementation 'androidx.browser:browser:1.5.0'  //
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-perf-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database-ktx'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage-ktx'
    // Add the Firebase SDK for Crashlytics.
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-crashlytics:18.3.6'
}
```

Comment: "After the latest update"   what updates  are you referring? did u make any update to dependencied version

Comment: No, it's just android studio new version.

Comment: So are you using canary version or the beta version?

Comment: Android Studio Flamingo

Answer (score 1):

This looks like you had added similar dependencies twice, due to which some classes are getting conflicted due to same name

```
 implementation "androidx.compose.material:material:1.4.2"
 implementation "androidx.compose.material3:material3-android:1.1.0-beta02"
```

just try, removing (or commenting) one of them with sync-build

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing changed.